# Quick sort partition tweak

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

but I am trying to figure out how I can make so I may choose which ever pivot point I wish, Say for example on this list of integers, 8, 7, 1, 9 , 11, 5 , 6, I wished to choose say key 6 as the pivot point in my code. Or if I wanted to choose 9 or whatever. How could I write this into my code? Any help is much appreciated.

```
package quicksort;

public class quicky {
    private static void quicksort(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
        int index = partition(arr, left, right);
    
        if(left < index - 1)
            quicksort(arr, left, index - 1);
        if(index < right)
            quicksort(arr, index, right);
    }
    private static int partition (int[] arr, int left, int right) {
        int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
        while(left<= right) {
            while(arr[left] < pivot) left++;
            while(arr[right]> pivot) right--;
        
            if(left<= right) {
                int tmp = arr[left];
                arr[left] =arr[right];
                arr[right] = tmp;
            
                left++;
                right--;
            }
        }
        return left;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[] array = new int [] { 8, 7, 1, 9, 11, 5, 6};
        quicksort(array, 0 , array.length-1);
        for(int i = 0; i <array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(array[i]+ " ");        
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: What should happen if the desired pivot value is not in the array?

Comment: Could you please mention why you would like to do that? Also, there is a variant of quicksort known as the randomized quicksort. Are you expecting to do something similar?

Comment: I would like to be able to show how pivot points work, so if I wanted to show how just half of the array can be sorted based on a pivot point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple method:

1. Check if value exists in array.
2. If it does, swap value with value in default pivot index.
3. Proceed using same code/ lomuto partition.

Answer (score 1):

Here in your code

```
private static int partition (int[] arr, int left, int right) {
/*
Here in below code only you need to make your changes and that needs to be through out the same as you are calling this from quicksort also you need to make use of the left and right for that, as everytime you will be passing that otherwise it will be static value. 

like you can do 
int pivot = arr[left] // for left most as pivot, if you want the last one then have arr[right] as pivot, right now you have mid element as pivot.
*/        
int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
        

        while(left<= right) {
            while(arr[left] < pivot) left++;
            while(arr[right]> pivot) right--;
        
            if(left<= right) {
                int tmp = arr[left];
                arr[left] =arr[right];
                arr[right] = tmp;
            
                left++;
                right--;
            }
        }
        return left;
    }
```